# Expand Video and Photo thumbnail size rails

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jwplayer, nested-attributes

I have a project model where i create different projects. Each project have a Title, Description and many assets. The assets are nested attributes to the project containing attached photos and videos.(This means that in every project you can upload many videos and photos.)

My project Index looks like a photo gallery, listing every projects first image as a thumbnail.
My project show displays the project title, desc, and all photos as thumbnails (130 x 130 px).
When clicking on a photo thumbnail, this asset.photo.url get stored in a div that shows up over the thumbnails with the original size(The popup div). The div changes photo depending on which thumbnail you click on. If you don't understand look at the code below.

The problem is that I don't know who to make a similar effect with the videos. The videos will also get displayed as a thumbnail but can't figure out how to display it in the div. I am using jwplayer and I don't know how to fill the popup div with my js video player code.

Here is my Project.show.html.erb:

```
<div style=" height: 40%;">
<h1 class="center">
  <%= @project.title %>
</h1>
<hr></hr>
<div>
    <div class="form-signin-show">
      <br />
      <% if @project.description? %>
        <p style=" margin-bottom: 5%;" >
        <%=raw @project.description.html_safe.gsub(/\r\n?/,"<br/>").html_safe %>
        </p>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <p id="popup" align="center"></p>

<div class="row" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; text-align: center;">   
  <div class="thumball"> 
<% @project.assets.each do |asset| %>
  <% if asset.photo.file? %>
    <li class="thumbnail span1 col-md-2" style="border: none; display: inline-block !important; float: none !important; position: relative;">
       <%= link_to asset.photo.url, class: :popup_link, target: :_blank do %>
       <span class="roll" ></span>
         <%= image_tag asset.photo.url(:thumb) %>
      <% end %>  
    </li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<hr></hr>


<div class="center" id="gohere">
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>
</div><br /><br />


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.thumbnail').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 1500);
    return false; 
});
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".popup_link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#popup").html( $('<img>').attr('src', this.href) );
     });
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#popup").click(function() {
$("#popup img").remove();

});
  });

$(function() {
// OPACITY OF BUTTON SET TO 0%
$(".roll").css("opacity","0");

// ON MOUSE OVER
$(".roll").hover(function () {

// SET OPACITY TO 70%
$(this).stop().animate({
opacity: .7
}, "fast");
},


// ON MOUSE OUT
function () {

// SET OPACITY BACK TO 50%
$(this).stop().animate({
opacity: 0
}, "slow");
});
});


</script>
```

This code work the "filling popup div with original image size:

```
<%= link_to asset.photo.url, class: :popup_link, target: :_blank do %>

$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".popup_link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#popup").html( $('<img>').attr('src', this.href) );
     });
  });
```

I'm thinking of a similar solution, displaying video thumbs and when clicked, link the js code to the popup div.

Here is the js code for displaying a video thumbnail:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      jwplayer("video").setup({
          flashplayer: "<%=asset_path('jwplayer.flash.swf')%>",
          file: "<%= asset.object.video.url(:original) %>",
          primary: "flash",
          height: 160,
          width: 160,
          analytics: {
              enabled: false,
             cookies: false
         }
      });
      </script>
```

Would appreciate some help, maybe if you got some other solution like popup the video in original size and dimm the background when someone click on the video thumbnail. Or if it's possible to do the same solution as with the photos. I'm pretty new to Ruby... Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Don't know how to approach it, tried something like this but it did not work out well.. Think the problem lies in my javascript, with the img tags and such, don't know how to do it for an Video.

```
 <div style=" height: 40%;">
    <h1 class="center">
      <%= @project.title %>
    </h1>
    <hr></hr>
    <div>
        <div class="form-signin-show">
          <br />
          <% if @project.description? %>
            <p style=" margin-bottom: 5%;" >
            <%=raw @project.description.html_safe.gsub(/\r\n?/,"<br/>").html_safe %>
            </p>
            <% end %>
          </div>
          <p id="popup" align="center"></p>
          <p id="video" align="center"></p> <!-- Display the original Video --!>


    <div class="row" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; text-align: center;">   
      <div class="thumball"> 
    <% @project.assets.each do |asset| %>
      <% if asset.photo.file? %>
        <li class="thumbnail span1 col-md-2" id="thumb1"style="border: none; display: inline-block !important; float: none !important; position: relative;">
           <%= link_to asset.photo.url, class: :popup_link, target: :_blank do %>
           <span class="roll" ></span>
             <%= image_tag asset.photo.url(:thumb) %>
          <% end %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

<!--------------------------- Video thumbs ----------------------------------!>
           <div class="thumball"> 
    <% @project.assets.each do |asset1| %>
      <% if asset1.video.file? %>
        <li class="thumbnail span1 col-md-2" id="thumb2"style="border: none; display: inline-block !important; float: none !important; position: relative;">
           <%= link_to asset1.video.url, class: :popup_link, target: :_blank do %>
           <span class="roll" ></span>
             <%= image_tag asset1.video.url(:thumb) %>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          jwplayer("video").setup({
              flashplayer: "<%=asset_path('jwplayer.flash.swf')%>",
              file: "<%= asset1.video.url(:original) %>",
              primary: "flash",
              height: 160,
              width: 160,
              analytics: {
                  enabled: false,
                 cookies: false
             }
          });
          </script> 
    <% end %>


<!--------------------------- Video thumbs END----------------------------------!>
    <hr></hr>


    <div class="center" id="gohere">
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>
    </div><br /><br />


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#thumb1').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 1500);
        return false; 
    });
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".popup_link").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#popup").html( $('<img>').attr('src', this.href) );
         });
      });
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#popup").click(function() {
    $("#popup img").remove();

    });
      });

<!--------------------- TAKING THE VIDEO URL PATH -----------------!>

      <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#thumb2').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 1500);
        return false; 
    });
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".popup_link").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#video").html( $('<img>').attr('src', this.href) );
         });
      });
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#video").click(function() {
    $("#video img").remove();

    });
      });

    $(function() {
    // OPACITY OF BUTTON SET TO 0%
    $(".roll").css("opacity","0");

    // ON MOUSE OVER
    $(".roll").hover(function () {

    // SET OPACITY TO 70%
    $(this).stop().animate({
    opacity: .7
    }, "fast");
    },


    // ON MOUSE OUT
    function () {

    // SET OPACITY BACK TO 50%
    $(this).stop().animate({
    opacity: 0
    }, "slow");
    });
    });


    </script>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of where you have the player running like this so we can check what is happening?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer  Added an Example though its totally wrong. Might give an idea of what I'm trying to do. :)

Comment: Sorry, by example, I meant a link.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer Some thing like this, showing the video when clicking on another div. http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/featuredcontentglider.htm

Comment: Where are you trying this with the JW Player?